# How to run multiple threads at once and each of them increment a counter?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to simulate a race between threads, but some of the threads do not start. How can I implement the run method in such a way that every Competitor Thread increments a Counter and when the counter reaches value 100 the winner thread is announce in the RaceContext. There are 10 teams with 4 ThreadCompetitors in each of them... This is what I've done so far :

race class:

```
public class RelayRace {
    private List<RelayRaceTeam> teamList = new ArrayList<>(10);

    public RelayRace() {
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("FERRARI"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("BMW"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("LAMBORGHINI"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("DACIA"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("NASCAR"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("OPEL"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("MITSUBISHI"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("HONDA"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("PORSCHE"));
        teamList.add(new RelayRaceTeam("MERCEDES"));

    }

    public void start() {
        teamList.forEach(RelayRaceTeam::start);
    }
}
```

TeamClass:

```
public class RelayRaceTeam extends Thread {
    private static final ThreadRaceContext context = new ThreadRaceContext();
    private ArrayList<RelayRaceCompetitor> competitors = new ArrayList<>(4);
    private String name;

    public RelayRaceTeam(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            competitors.add(new RelayRaceCompetitor());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        competitors.forEach(RelayRaceCompetitor::start);

        for (RelayRaceCompetitor competitor : competitors) {
            System.out.println("Competitor " + competitor.getNumber() + " from team " +
                    name + " has traversed " + Count.getCounter());
        }

        if (Count.getCounter() == 100) {
            synchronized (context) {
                context.announceWhichTeamWon(name, competitors);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Competitor:

```
public class RelayRaceCompetitor extends Thread{
    private int number;
    private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public RelayRaceCompetitor() {
        number = count.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Count.increment();
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

The context where the winner is announced :

```
public class ThreadRaceContext extends Thread {
    public void announceWhichTeamWon(String name, ArrayList<RelayRaceCompetitor> competitors) {
        System.out.println(name + " won the competition");
        for (RelayRaceCompetitor competitor : competitors) {
            System.out.println("Competitor number : " + competitor.getNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

And the counter :

```
public class Count {
    private static int counter = 1;

    public static void increment() {
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question/issue? Also you may want to look into [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: Your code/description is a little difficult for me to understand, but from your question title, if you to need a separate counter for each thread on the same object, look at `ThreadLocal` class.

Comment: Just some things I noticed. You are accessing the Counter without proper concurrency solutions. Also, if it's a race of threads, each thread should have its own Counter, not a shared one.

Comment: I don't get it. You have 10 teams, each team has 4 members. When you start each member of each team **once** increments the counter and then dies. The counter starts with 1 and reaches 41. So, 100 is never reached. Is this what is called *racing* nowadays? ;-)

Comment: As noted It's not clear what is your question. But It seems that [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Calling `t[i].start()` for each thread `t[i]` in a list is _not_ a fair start.  The start() function is heavy-weight:  It's what actually creates the new thread.  What you want to do instead is have all of the threads wait at a _barrier_, and then lift the barrier when they're all ready.  `CyclicBarrier` (as suggested by Ilya, above) is good for that.